# How can ensure that the values put in textbox are of integer type?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to use `int.TryParse` when defining properties for a field?
What I want to accomplish, is to check if users haven't accidentally inserted string instead of an integer. I can't figure this out. Any ideas and hints would be really helpful.

Edition:
What I wanted to do is - user puts value in the textbox, and after presing button, getset property evaluates if the value that user has put in the textbox is integer. Any other data type is not valid, so in case, if user has put in string or char, the message box is showed with message "Please insert number" Hope I have made it a bit easier to understand what I really try to accomplish
Here is example code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>();
    myList.Add(new myClass { Skaitlis1 = textBox1.Text });
    foreach (myClass pers in myList)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(pers.Skaitlis1);
    }
}

class myClass
{
    private int skaitlis1;
    public int Skaitlis1
    {
        get { return skaitlis1; }
        set
        {
            int a;
            if (int.TryParse(value, out a))
            {
                skaitlis1 = a;
            }
            else
            {
                skaitlis1 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That certainly looks like what you're describing but you're mixing up strings and integers. What's the issue with the code? Do you have an error you'd like to share?

Comment: You cant change the types inside your property.  Another suggestion would be to use another property, make it an int, readonly and set it inside your string set.

Comment: Please review [ask] for a thorough description of how best to ask questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you, I will definately check  "How to ask", but for now I have updated original post to make it easier to understand. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is really what you're after, but it sounds like you want to have a string property that can only be set if the user passes a string that can be converted to an int?

If so, then what you have will (almost) work if you just change the type of the backing field to an int:

```
private class myClass
{
    private int skaitlis1;

    public string Skaitlis1
    {
        get { return skaitlis1.ToString(); }
        set { int.TryParse(value, out skaitlis1); }
    }
}
```

.

```
var x = new myClass();
x.Skaitlis1 = "hello";
Console.WriteLine("The value of Skaitlis1 is: {0}", x.Skaitlis1);

x.Skaitlis1 = "12";
Console.WriteLine("Now the value of Skaitlis1 is: {0}", x.Skaitlis1);

// Output:
// The value of Skaitlis1 is: 0
// Now the value of Skaitlis1 is: 12
```

.

Otherwise, if you just want an `int` property, then make it an `int` instead of a `string`:

```
public int Skaitlis1 { get; set; }
```

Using an int property in the class is best, and now you move your validation logic to the UI side:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value))
    {
        // This is from your code above. The logic does not make sense in that
        // it is doing a lot of extra work to just add 'value' to the listBox1.
        // I assume in reality you're actually adding 'myClass' to a global list?

        List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>();
        myList.Add(new myClass { Skaitlis1 = value });

        foreach (myClass pers in myList)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(pers.Skaitlis1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a valid integer!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What I wanted to do is - user puts value in the textbox, and after presing button, getset property evaluates if the value that user has put in the textbox is integer. Any other data type is not valid, so in case, if user has put in string or char, the message box is showed with message "Please insert number" Hope I have made it a bit easier to understand  what I really try to accomplish.

Comment: Your class property should then be of the type you expect (`int`). The client side can validate the user input. The class itself should probably not show a message box. On the client side, before you set the property, you would do the `int.TryParse` check and show a message box BEFORE trying to set the property.

Comment: @N.Pelss I updated the sample with code that would validate the entry before setting the property (see the last sample).

Answer (score 0):

If you are really trying to store a string property, but want to make sure the property is passable as an int, then you are on the right track.  Just don't use the `TryParse` evaluated result (unless to want to convert it back to a `string`).

```
class myClass
{
    private string skaitlis1;
    public string Skaitlis1
    {
        get { return skaitlis1; }
        set
        {
            int a;
            if (int.TryParse(value, out a))
            {
                skaitlis1 = value;
            }
            else
            {
                skaitlis1 = "0";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to change your property to an int and ensure the value before creation, then you could do something like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int val;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out val))
    {
      List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>();
      myList.Add(new myClass { Skaitlis1 = val });

      foreach (myClass pers in myList)
      {
          listBox1.Items.Add(pers.Skaitlis1);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid value.  Must be numeric.");
    }
}

class myClass
{
    public int Skaitlis1 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: No, I am trying to store an integer and I want to check if users havent accidentally put in string or any aother data type value in the textbox.

Comment: Then your property needs to be an int, and you need to do the TryParse in order to call the setter on it. assuming you declare an `int val` earlier in your first code segment, then you can call `myList.Add(new myClass { Skaitlis1 = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out val)?val:0 });`

Comment: I have considered this option, but by using this scenario it means that if user accidentally puts in a string and doesnt notice it, program will continue to execute with default value, but I can not let this happen! User has to put in valid integer, and not string or char.

Comment: Then you need to enforce you constraint in the UI (in the TextBox), by not permitting the user to enter anything else.  Or by popping a message box when the `TryParse` returns false, and not adding the object.

Comment: Please dont laugh at me, but this is how I understood your last sentence: myList.Add(new myClass { Skaitlis1 = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out val) ? val : MessageBox.Show("Enter valid integer") }); Ofcourse it doesnt work. I guess you just can not write it down in one line like this

Comment: You would need to do the TryParse before creating your class.  If it succeeds, then add it.  I will add a second code block above, showing that.